# How to return string '2016-06-27 05:29:39' in the datetime MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM in MySQL 2008

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

I am working on a tool having two consoles on for select query which is returning the date in string format and then I need to insert the data returned from select query into another table.

`select dt_logged from DATA_FORM_VALUES_1125505`

```
insert into dbo.ps_mnd_reqeng_sc_projectsummary
(
logged_date
)
VALUES
(
convert(DATETIME,:column1,101)
)
```

Comment: See the manual- although I'd handle this in application code, preferably JavaScript which operates in the locale of the end user.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO test (date) VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('11/29/2018 07:06:03', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%m:%s'))

SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%m:%s') FROM test